# using Azure Service Bus for non-organic traffic

Tags: azure, queue, azureservicebus, throttling

We have a system which is used for searching items inside our database. Sometimes this system subjected to non-organic traffic by robots. We cannot classify it as DDOS attack but datamining, because they search for valid items. Now we want to use Azure Service Bus queue for all non-organic requests having a delay and save backend systems.

How we can achive it? is it a good solution?

**Update**
This is a web application which is hosted on our on-prem and gets http/https requests. We want to move the GUI part to Azure and make it stable to manage this kind of data-mining. I don't know which kind of queues suite our problem.

Comment: You basically want to queue those bot calls and handle it separately. If you don't need any atomic operations and message ordering guarantee you can even do this using azure storage queue which will be cheaper. You can probably have a worker role or web job to gradually process the messages in the queue.

Comment: @user217648 Is this a website that has requests coming to it over HTTP/HTTPS?

Comment: Please see the updates